# Multiprocessing with Process and Error: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pickle

I just can't get any further on a problem and I don't understand why. I do multiprocessing which also works great in a mini example. But when I build it into the "big" code it doesn't work anymore. Maybe someone could explain the mistake to me "easier" or tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Blabla Errorlog...
...

File "C:\Users\XXX\eclipse-workspace\ADAScarfs_v1.4\fem\_ModelGenerator.py", line 333, in _generateNodeObj
nodesAdh.start()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
return Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

The code where the error occours:

```
nodesAdh = multiprocessing.Process(target=myScarfMeshR3D.generateAdhesiveNodesObject, args=(_sectionAdh,))
        nodesAdh.start()
```

Comment: `mp.Process` tries to serialize (pickle) your passed arguments but something is holding a lock object, these can't be pickled. Maybe reading [that here](https://bugs.python.org/issue13569) will help you to understand.

Comment: hey Thanks for your answer. After telling my rubberducky this Problem (we had a really serious talk) I think I know the solution. The problem is that I tried to "read" something from a file earlier. I save some stuff inside variables and I guess here is the dog berried. Since I assume that everything is a reference there musst be some kind of reference to the reading of the variable of the file. The easy and for me fastest solution was to put everything into a dictionary and hand that over to the processes. Problem solved the ugly way, but always remember life is short, so eat dessert first :)

Comment: No idea what your target-function here is about, but it seems it holds a thread-instance and that will fail on pickling. Anyway, I'm glad you and your rubberducky could figure it out ;)